# Auto assign a shop manager to a new WooCommerce order based on variable increment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to assign every new order to a list of shop managers. What I need is like a queue, so every time a new order is created assign to the next shop manager in the queue.

This is the code I have:

```php
function before_checkout_create_order($order, $data) {
    global $i;
    switch ($i) {
        case 0:
            $user = get_user_by('email', 'firstShopManagere@example.com');
            break;
        case 1:
            $user = get_user_by('email', 'secondShopManager@example.com');
            $i=0;
            break;
    }
    $userLastName = $user->user_lastname;
    $order->update_meta_data('asesor_asignado',$userLastName);  
    $i++;
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);
```

The problem I'm dealing with now is that the `$i` variable can't be stored even though I increment the value that doesn't change so that the next time the value is **0** again. Also every time `$i` reaches **4**, it should go back to **0**

Any advice?

Comment: What about looking at the last id inserted or the length of the queue then using a modulo operator with the number of shop managers?

Comment: @Almaju how can I look for the last ID inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage `$i` you can use the following WordPress functions:

- [add_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) - Adds a new option
- [update_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) - Updates the value of an option that was already added
- [get_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) - Retrieves an option value based on an option name

These will allow you to modify or reset `$i` every time the hook callback function is called

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    // Initialize
    $i = 0;
    $user = '';

    // Option does not exist
    if ( ! get_option( 'my_counter') ) {
        // Adds a new option
        add_option( 'my_counter', $i );
    } else {
        // Get value
        $i = get_option( 'my_counter' );
    }

    // Compare
    switch ( $i ) {
        case 0:
            $user_name = 'user_0';
            break;
        case 1:
            $user_name = 'user_1';
            break;
        case 2:
            $user_name = 'user_2';
            break;
        case 3:
            $user_name = 'user_3';
            break;
        case 4:
            $user_name = 'user_4';
            break;
    }

    // Update meta data
    $order->update_meta_data( 'asesor_asignado', $user_name ); 
   
    // $i less than
    if ( $i < 4 ) {
        // increment
        $i++;
    } else {
        // Reset
        $i = 0;
    }

    // Updates the value of an option that was already added
    update_option( 'my_counter', $i );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 10, 2 );
```